# How to run Capistrano task on failed deploy

Tags: ruby, capistrano

Using Capistrano I'd like to run a cleanup/teardown task on failed deploy, such as when a shell command fails.

I couldn't find anything after a fairly extensive search.

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: `cap -T` shows you all commands and their descriptions.

Comment: @JacobDam, yes, but how does that help me with my question? I need something like this pseudo code in deploy.rb: after "failed_deploy", :my_cleanup_task

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I thought you asked which task to cleanup a failed deploy. So, your question is: How to trigger a failed deploy, and run a custom cleanup task programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on Capistrano source code:

- https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb
- https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb

It depends on how your task is. Basically, there are some snippets for rolling back thing:

```
task :my_task do
  on_rollback { "rm -rf data_dir" }
  exec "mkdir data_dir"
  exec "some commands for preparaing data in data_dir" 
end
after "deploy:create_symlink", :my_task
```

In above case, `my_task` should be run in a transaction. And yes, it's already in transaction because `deploy:create_symlink` is a subtask of `deploy` which creates a transaction.

If you want to run `my_task` standalone (not a subtask of `cap deploy` process). You should create another task like below, and run `cap my_task_standalone` from command line.

```
task :my_task_standalone do
  transaction do
    my_task
  end
end
```